# Its saying that I have illegal characters but I don't know how to fix that

Tags: java

```
public final class Hw7pr2

{

public static void main(String[] args)

     {

System.out.println(“Starting …….”);

Scanner scan =new scanner(system.in);

    log("Starting...");

     Pet pet = new Pet();

     work_like(pet);         

     pet = new Fish();

     work_like(pet);    

     pet = new dog();

     work_like(pet);    

     pet = new cat();

     work_like(pet);    

     log("Done.");

}

public static void work_like(Pet aPet)

{    aPet.walk();

}

private static class Pet

{

Public:

Char name[10], color[10];

    void prop()

   {

log("pet is: ");

system.out.println(“enter Name and color of pet”);

name=scan.nextchar();

color =scan.nextchar();

    }

}

private static final class Fish extends Pet

{

    @Override void prop()

    {

log("pet is fish...");

System.out.println(“Pet is fish”);

           }

}

private static final class dog extends Pet

   {

Char breed;

Int weight;

    @Override void prop()

       {

log("Pet is Dog ");

system.out.println(“Enter the breed”);

breed =scan.nextchar();

system.out.println(“Enter weight of the dog”);

weight=scan.nextchar();

       }

}

private static final class cat extends Pet

   {

Char coat;

    @Override void prop()

       {

log("Pet is cat");

system.out.println(“Enter Name and color of pet”);

coat =scan.nextchar();

       }

}

private static void log(String aMessage)

   {

    System.out.println(aMessage);

}

}
```

It keeps saying that I have a lot of illegal characters but I don't know what that is so can someone help me?

Comment: Please format your question. This is very hard to read.

Comment: please read the rules & regulations before posting. This question would be much clearer if you gave an explanation of what you're doing and gave the stack trace or line number where error occurs

Comment: 1) Format your code.  2) Include the *exact* and *complete* error message.  3) If a line number is identified in the error message, identify that line in your listing.

Comment: System has a capital s

Comment: public has a lower case p

Comment: Scanner has a capital `S`. This code makes one want to scratch their own eyes out. I'm finding it hard to believe you wrote this on your own.

Comment: There shouldn't be a colon after public

Comment: None of your other classes are going to be able to access the variable "scan" which is declared in your main method.

Comment: So many errors... Java is case-sensitive. Pay attention to your caps.

Answer (score 4):

In case you copied that from MS Word, this line looks wrong (dots):

```
System.out.println(“Starting …….”);
```

Comment: And this is the least of your problems. I can see at 5 other errors that are going to prevent your code from compiling.

Comment: Yep, many more problems. Still, OP asked for illegal characters and there they are. Together with an explanation where they might come from. These errors are sometimes hard to catch and happen quite often when pasting from other programs.